# Rename a column name in dataframe which has some similar string as old name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I want to rename a column name in dataframe. Data is coming on fly and column name may contain some non english characters as well. So I am looking for something like:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'string include (oldName1)': 'newName1', 'string include (oldName2)': 'newName2'}
```

Present rename function in Pandas is:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

This function require exact column name 'oldName1'. I want to rename column even if old name includes some string like/in 'oldName1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.columns.str.contains`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'oldName1': [1,1], 'zzzoldName2': [2,2], 'someoldName3': [3,3]})

converters = {'oldName1': 'newName1','oldName2': 'newName2','oldName3': 'newName3'}
conversion_map = {df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(old)][0]: new for old, new in converters.items()}

df.rename(columns=conversion_map)

>>    newName1  newName3  newName2
0         1         3         2
1         1         3         2
```

Note that the `[0]` will return the first match, so you may want to check `conversion_map` to see how the name is changed. If a name cannot be found this way it will raise an  `IndexError`